# Emails not sending with Mailkit or .net smtp client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mailkit

The native MVC UserManager.sendasync works great. But when i instantiate an Email service and try to send an email ... no dice. I made a php script to send the email. Works beatuifully super easy. I also tried downloading and using Mailkit... no dice. Im not sure what to do here. No error message

```
var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
                mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("System", "system@my.hypertarget.io"));
                mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Jason", "unblockgames@gmail.com"));
                mimeMessage.Subject = "Test";
                mimeMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain"){Text = message};
                using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
                    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
                    client.Connect("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25, false);
                    client.Capabilities &= ~SmtpCapabilities.Pipelining;
                    client.Send(mimeMessage);
                    client.Disconnect(true);
                }
```

Comment: The MailKit code above looks fine. Have you tried testing it in a simple console application? Does it throw an exception? If so, what is the exception? Could your ASP.NET webapp be going out of scope on the web server before it finishes sending a message?

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! the problem wasnt with this code at all. But since you told me i was able to find the real problem. your a hero